# Route [RemindersController@postRemind] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4, routes

Implementing Laravels password reminded function but hitting this error:

```
Route [RemindersController@postRemind] not defined
```

So far using artisan I have added the controller, and ran dump-autoload then created my page.

In a users folder I have my view called:

```
passwordremind.blade.php
```

This contains a form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'RemindersController@postRemind', 'class' => 'small-form')) }}

  <h3>Reset your password</h3>

  {{ Form::text('email', $value = null, array('placeholder' => 'Email Address', 'class'=> 'form-control','autofocus' => 'autofocus' )) }}
  {{ Form::submit('Send Request', array('class' => 'btn btn-success sign-in-btn')) }}
  {{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-facebook left-float-icon"></i> Login in', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary fb-login-btn')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

But this gives me the error and I cant see why? I have implemented this before and cannot remember defining the route specifically?

Comment: add your routes file

Comment: Nothing has been added to my routes for this controller, nothing in the laravel docs to say so?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to add this to my routes:

```
Route::controller('password', 'RemindersController');
```